# Graphon model for random graphs and almost surely dense graphs

Tags: law-of-large-numbers, random-graphs

Consider the [random graph generating process from a graphon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphon#Statistical_formulation).

> A random graph model is an exchangeable random graph model if and only if it can be defined in terms of a (possibly random) graphon.

> It follows from this definition and the law of large numbers that, if
> $W\ne0$, exchangeable random graph models are dense almost surely

But what if I define $W(x,y)=10^{-6}\ \forall (x,y)\in[0,1]^2$? I don't see why this would produce dense graphs almost surely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dense graphs are graphs with $\Theta(n^2)$ edges. Graphs sampled from your graphon have $10^{-6} \binom n2$ edges in expectation (and the number of edges is highly concentrated around this mean). That's still $\Theta(n^2)$.

Comment: So Erdos-Renyi graphs are dens a.s. as well? What if I defined W to be zero outside of $[0,10^{-6}]^2$? Even in the case of my original question that you just answered, my (wrong) intuition tells my that I could have chosen $W=0.49$ and the graphs would not be dense a.s., why is this wrong? Can you really say a graph is dense if it has less than half the edges it could have?

Comment: I understand your reluctance to call such graphs dense! You should let go of your intuitive definition of "dense" and just take the mathematical one: if, as $n \to \infty$, at least a constant fraction of the $\binom n2$ are present, the graph is dense. So, yes: if $W(x,y) = 10^{-6}$ on $[0,10^{-6}]^2$, and $0$ outside that, then the graphs will be dense almost surely, because they will almost surely have around $10^{-18} \binom n2$ edges.

Comment: Erdos-Renyi graphs with a constant edge probability are dense a.s., but if the probability varies with $n$, they might not be. For instance, we often talk about Erdos-Renyi graphs with edge probability $p = \frac{c}{n}$, or $p = \frac{\log n}{n}$, or $p = n^{-\alpha}$ for $0 < \alpha < 1$, and these are all different kinds of sparse random graphs. To give another example, random regular graphs with a fixed degree (or even with degree $o(n)$) are sparse.